# C# Asp Net Core Config

Tags: c#, config

I have a console project in .NetCore where I am working with a database and I have configured the string connections from the database in an App.config.
Then in my class DataBaseClass I use them like that:

```
string dbConfig = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConfig"].ConnectionString;
```

Now I am trying to make an Asp Net Core project in which I need to use the class DataBaseClass but I get an error on that string connection saying: Reference not set to an instance of an object.
How can I use that class with those configurations in my project?

Comment: While you can, using a compatibility package, you *shouldn't*. The configuration system in .NET Core is completely different and doesn't force you to use `ConfigurationManager` throughout your code. You only need to configure this once and inject configuration objects to your classes. Check [ASP.NET Core Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Despite the name, the same classes and calls work for command-line or desktop applications

Comment: Specifically for connection strings, there's a shortcut [that will load connection strings from settings by name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/sql?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)